# Organigrams in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

hi everyone I am a newbie to latex and i'm stck in making an organigram with tikz package can anyone help please 
[image: organigram i want to make]

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={rounded rectangle,draw,align=center}]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=4]
  \node (A) {Service\\ A};
  \node[right=of A] (B) {Service\\ B};
  \node[right=of B] (C) {Service\\ C};
  \node[right=of C] (D) {Service\\ D};
 \end{scope}
 \node[above=7em of 4] (Dir){Directeur};
 \node[below left=2em and 4em of Dir.south] (Bur){Bureau};
 \node[below right=2em and 4em of Dir.south] (Sec){Secretatiat};`

Comment: `\node[below=1ex of D.south east,anchor=north east] (un) {unreadable};
 \node[below=1ex of un.south east,anchor=north east] (un2) {unreadable2};
 \foreach \X in {A,B,C,D}
 {\draw[-stealth] (Dir.south) -- ++ (0,-4.5em) -| (\X);}
 \draw[-stealth] (Dir) -| (Bur);
 \draw[-stealth] (Dir) -| (Sec);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`